Replacing a string with a variable which contains newlines
I would like to replace a string with the a variable which contains newlines in it. However, sed replacing doesn't seem to do what I want.

What I am doing now

    str=""
    str+="#My header 1"$'\n'
    str+="#My header 2"$'\n'
    str+="#My header 3"$'\n'

    echo "$str"

    #My header 1
    #My header 2
    #My header 3
    
    sed "s/##HEADER##/${str}/g" myfile.out

Unfortunately this does not work obtaining the following error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unterminated s command
Any other ideas?

Did you try \\n instead of \n?

@testing-ma-lady No, I did not. However it does work! Could you please put it in an answer to accept it?

I rarely use sed, but I think that literal newlines inside a substitution string are not permitted.

bash expands $'\n' as a real newline character (ASCII code 10). Your str variable thus contains 3 newline characters. However newline characters are meaningful to sed. It uses them as command separators (among other things). If you want sed to output a newline character, and if your sed supports it (e.g., GNU sed) you can encode it as \n. Example to add a newline after word foo:
sed 's/foo/foo\n/' <<< "barfoobar"
barfoo
bar

In your case do not use $'\n', use plain \n in your text string:
str=""
str+="#My header 1\n"
str+="#My header 3\n"
str+="#My header 2\n"
sed "s/##HEADER##/${str}/g" myfile.out


Note that interpreting \n (and several other similar escape sequences) is not a standard sed feature. As far as I know, it only works in GNU sed.

@GordonDavisson You're right, POSIX specifies that \n is supported in a regular expression but not necessarily in a replacement text. Note that the sed that comes with macOS (a BSD sed, I think) also supports it.
